# Automatically tell new users to reference their answers

Tags: feature-request, references

Being very active on skepitcs.se last week, I realized this site **gets too many** unreferenced answers, this will cause answers to get deleted or make the moderators comment on the answer and asking the answerer to reference their answer (waste of time, waste of energy).

Usually, google links to one of skeptics.se's questions and new users sign up (you can see that with their 1 reputation) and post an answer.

Most of new users don't check any FAQ pages nor they know that this site has some strict rules for answers.

I think it would be productive to tell the answerer (new members only) to reference their answer.

Adding a banner above the answer box sounds like a good practice:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried out the answer form as an anonymous user? There is something very similar already available.

Comment: I just checked and found it, maybe it can be edited to ask for reference more explicitly and also the box should be brought to new signed up members.

Comment: @MadScientist: Wow... I didn't know it did that now... and yet so many people aren't heeding it :-(

Comment: Maybe we can add a reminder pop up to reference if no link is found in the body of the answer.

Comment: @Sklivvz, I thought of that. But sometimes people reference books and paper without linking to them using the APA citation or else.

Comment: @georgechalhoub yes, but we can get around that with the correct wording: "You have no links in your answer. We expect all answers to include references, which are usually, but not always, links to external resources. If your answer contains non-link references please ignore this message and proceed!"

Comment: @Sklivvz, possible also; but I still prefer the idea of the banner, because many people link sometimes to sites like livescience.com or wikipedia thinking it is a good source.

Comment: @Sklivvz, when my reputation was 1 on this site, I saw that this box is kinda added, does it mean that this feature-request has been accomplished?